# How to change extension of all files in a directory?

Tags: bash, rename

There are some extensionless files in current directory (there are not dot in their names).

I want to rename like so:

```
filename -> filename.md
```

I tried doing `mv * *.md` but that didn't help.

I am interested in a function that takes an argument for the extension and renames accordingly, and the another one for the files to perform operation on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Patterns are matched by the shell, not by the command, so what you tried had no chance to work: *first* the shell expands `*` to all files (not just the extensionless ones: you never said anything about the files not having a `.` in their name), and `*.md` to all files whose name in `.md`; then the shell passes the concatenation of the two lists to the `mv` command.

### In zsh

In zsh, run the following command once (put them in your `~/.zshrc` for the future):

```
autoload -U zmv
# you don't need the following two now, but put them also in your .zshrc
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

You can then run [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) to rename files according to a pattern. Both the [pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) and the replacement text need to be quoted so that they are passed-as is to the `zmv` function which will expand them in due course.

```
zmv '^*.*' '$f.md'
```

Note the single quotes around both arguments: the pattern and the replacement expression must be passed literally to the `zmv` function.

`^*.*` means all files except the ones matching `*.*`, it's a shortcut for `*~*.*` (both are zsh extensions to the traditional pattern syntax). If you want to use this pattern outside `zmv`, you need to run `setopt extended_glob` first (put that in your `.zshrc` too).

### In bash

Bash has no such convenient tool, so you have to resort to a loop. First, activate ksh globbing extensions; that's something you should put in yout `~/.bashrc`.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Now you can use the `!(PATTERN)` operator to match extensionless files.

```
for x in !(*.*); do
  mv -- "$x" "$x.md"
done
```

The double quotes arond `$x` are necessary in case the file names contain whitespace or globbing characters. The `--` after the command name is necessary in case a file name begins with `-`.

### In any shell

If you don't have the `!(…)` operator, you can loop over all files and test each file name inside the loop.

```
for x in *; do
  case "$x" in
    *.*) ;;         # skip this file
    *) mv -- "$x" "$x.md";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ah, yes, POSIX does allow an empty command list in `case` items. I think I got into the habit of using `:` from an old shell that didn't. I don't remember which one that would be.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `rename` (the one that comes with `perl` sometimes *renamed* `prename`). If there are other files in the directory, you'll need to exclude those as follows with an extglob:

```
shopt -s extglob
rename s/$/.md/ -- !(*.*)
```

Comment: That don't do anything. **rename --version** says `rename from util-linux 2.22.1`.

Comment: Oh, this is rename as shipped with perl. You might need to use `prename` instead.

Comment: There is no `prename` here on Fedora 18. I have **perl v5.16.2**

Comment: Hmm, minus one for fedora then. Grab it from http://kaarsemaker.net/static/downloads/prename - it's a pretty short and simple perl script.

Comment: Hm, that works. Can you tell me what is `!(*.*)` doing?

Comment: `!(patterns)` is extended pattern matching operator in BASH (switched on by `shopt -s extglob`) that matches anything except one of the given patterns. Look for `extglob` in `man bash`.

Answer (score 3):

Found a short answer [here](http://heatware.net/linux-unix/change-file-extensions-directory-linux/) (that also supports renaming, which is what I was looking for when I found this page):

```
for f in *.OLDNAME; do mv $f `basename $f .OLDNAME`.NEWNAME; done;
```

This also works to add or remove extensions, of course:

```
# Adding extension
for f in *; do mv $f ${f}.NEWNAME; done; # No need to use basename here -- just adding a new extension

# Removing extension
for f in *.OLDNAME; do mv $f `basename $f .OLDNAME`; done;
```

Comment: Doesn't really work if the file name contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a simpler way, but this one is fairly straightforward and the general form is adaptable to all kinds of purposes:

```
for name in *; do 
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then 
        mv -- "$name" "$name.md"
    fi
done
```

It could also be turned into a function.

Comment: Can you make it more readable, I mean can you spread it on multiple lines with proper indentation?

Comment: These **f** s are confusing me. Is `f` (between *for* and *in*) and `$f` same?

Comment: This renames all the files in the current directory, not just the extensionless ones.

Comment: @Gilles: True.  Rather than expand upon this, since you brought the definitive bomb anyway, I'll just +1 your answer.  And all apologies to Santosh for my original use of the one letter variable name, that was thoughtless.